# Where are line boxes drawn

Tags: css

```html
<div class="box">
    <a>ABC</a>
    <a>CBA</a>
</div>
```

```css
a {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

[image]

I've got a couple questions.

1. Can someone point out to me where the line box is? I am confused by this https://www.w3.org/TR/css-inline-3/#model

> Any block container that directly contains inline-level content—such as inline boxes, atomic inlines, and text runs—establishes an inline formatting context to lay out its contents.

So in my example, does that mean a line box is drawn around both a elements and the text inside of it, or only around the a element, or only around the text inside the a element...where is it drawn?

2. In the attached image, is the border drawing around the line box for each a element, or just its box model?
3. How can I visualize the line boxes around my inline-level elements with CSS (e.g. is there some property that gives a border around the line box).

Comment: A line box is a *line*. If all your text fit inside one line then you have one line box. If not, then you have more than one. Each line of text (or inline elements) is a line box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming (a) there is no other HTML or CSS and the elements take their default styling; and (b) the containing block is wide enough to take both `<a>` elements:

> 1. ... [Is] a line box is drawn around both a elements and the text
>    inside of it, or only around the a element, or only around the text
>    inside the a element...where is it drawn?

There is one line box. Vertically, from the upper edges of the half-leading above each text character to the lower edges of the half-leading below each text character. Horizontally, from the left content edge of the containing block to the right content edge of the containing block.

> 2. In the attached image, is the border drawing around the line box for each a element, or just its box model?

The border is drawn around the text for each element (since they do not have any padding). The border does not affect the height, width or placement of the line box.

> 3. How can I visualize the line boxes around my inline-level elements with CSS (e.g. is there some property that gives a border
>    around the line box).

There is no property, nor any other easy way to do it.

---

Update: To cover some of the follow-up comments:

> ... What causes the line box to be drawn, is it the inline a element, or the text run within the a element? In the css spec quote in my OP, it says both an inline box (a element) and text run establishes an inline formatting context. So in the code in the OP, what is the order of events for a line box being drawn, does the browser see the a element then create an inline formatting context or does it see the text run within the a element and then create an inline formatting context.

Suppose a block container contains a single non-atomic inline box which has no contents but has non-zero horizontal padding. This will generate a line box to contain that inline box. The line box will be the height of the leading around the strut of the line box. So we know that the box, not the text, is generating the line box. Note however, that if the box had zero horizontal padding, then either (a) the line box isn't created or (b) it has zero height (The CSS2 spec is vague on this point).

> My interpretation of your explanation of the order of events for a line box to be drawn is 1. An inline formatting context is arbitrarily created, 2. A line box is created within a block-level container, 3. inline elements are fitted to it. This does not quite make sense to me, because how would the browser know where and how many line box rows are needed e.g if text runs overflow.

I don't see the problem here. The number of line boxes is determined by the fitting process. A line box is created in the block container (not necessarily block-level). As many text runs and inline box fragments are fitted in to it as there is space for. If there are more text runs and box fragments, then another line box is created and the fitting process starts over. This continues until all the text runs and box fragments have been fitted into a line box.

> To my understanding, an inline formatting context is created when there are inline elements in a block container. So the order of events goes 1. Inline elements are placed within a block-level container 2. This triggers the block level container to create an inline formatting context. 3. The block level container then determines where line boxes should be drawn and how many rows are needed based on the location and size of text runs.

I don't see anything there that's functionally inconsistent with what I have said.

Comment: What is line box actually drawn around? Is it the a elements (the inline box) or the text inside the a elements?

Comment: @meghidey - Neither. As stated, vertically it's drawn around the leading.

Comment: Horizontally, it's not drawn "around" anything. It's drawn _first_, then _box fragments_ and _text runs_ are fitted in to it. Most line boxes will have some horizontal space left over; the width of the line box is not reduced.

Comment: I think a better way to rephrase my question, is what causes the line box to be drawn, is it the inline a element, or the text run within the a element? In the css spec quote in my OP, it says both an inline box (a element) and text run establishes an inline formatting context. So in the code in the OP, what is the order of events for a line box being drawn, does the browser see the a element then create an inline formatting context or does it see the text run within the a element and then create an inline formatting context.

Comment: And a secondary question to your comment, My interpretation of your explanation of the order of events for a line box to be drawn is 1. An inline formatting context is arbitrarily created, 2. A line box is created within a block-level container, 3. inline elements are fitted to it. This does not quite make sense to me, because how would the browser know where and how many line box rows are needed e.g if text runs overflow.

Comment: To my understanding, an inline formatting context is created when there are inline elements in a block container. So the order of events goes 1. Inline elements are placed within a block-level container 2. This triggers the block level container to create an inline formatting context. 3. The block level container then determines where line boxes should be drawn and how many rows are needed based on the location and size of text runs. Could you help clarify the order of events? Thanks

Comment: @meghidey - Addressing your follow-up questions is a bit long for the comments, so I've added an update to the answer for them.

Comment: Ohh I see, so 1. an inline box generates an line box, so the inline box determines the location of the line box,  then 2. the fitting process determines the number of line boxes needed to fit the inline boxes and text runs.